# Could not find file 'obj\Debug\VB prototype.exe'

Tags: vb.net

I've looked around for an answer and I have mostly found responses to the same error but where the file is already in use as apposed to it not being found as it in in my error.

My program will not compile, it takes around 15 seconds to fail and when is does so it presents me with this error which I don't know how I caused and I don't understand it.

```
    Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\VB prototype.exe" to "bin\Debug\VB prototype.exe". Could not find file 'obj\Debug\VB prototype.exe'. VB prototype
```

I checked and I do still have obj in debug in the file so I don't understand. 
I've tried moving the file, closing anything which could have access to the file and restarting the application and computer. The error changes from the one above to

```
VB prototype    Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\VB prototype.exe" to "bin\Debug\VB prototype.exe". Access to the path 'obj\Debug\VB prototype.exe' is denied.
```

Comment: Have you added your "obj" folder to source control?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the obj directory in projects folder.   You might have to close visual studio if you get a permissions error to delete the folder.   When you run the app again it should work assuming the code can compile

Comment: You mean the obj folder which contains the object code? If so I deleted that and then running the program but it came up with the same error.

Comment: Avast was deleting files in my obj folder. Mystery solved.